# DB2 11 query with anonymous table or hard list of values

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe, db2-zos

I'd like a DB2 compatible query for all the values in my own hardcoded list of values that are NOT in a table.  This query works well in Microsoft SQL Server

```
SELECT * FROM
  (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(7), (7000000)) as T(ID)
EXCEPT
  SELECT ID
  FROM ACCOUNT;
```

I'm aware of this answer [SQL - How can I return the IDs from a where clause list that are not in the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903178/sql-how-can-i-return-the-ids-from-a-where-clause-list-that-are-not-in-the-tabl) where they suggest using a VALUES clause.  Perhaps it works with other versions of DB2, but on mine I get the error "Illegal symbol (" so I'm not sure it likes the VALUES function in my version of DB2.

Comment: What is your Db2-server operating-system-platform ?  (z/os , i-series, linux/unix/windows) ?  Your syntax is valid for Linux/Unix/Windows v11.

Comment: I think it is on IBM Solaris.  When I run 'SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1' I get DSN11015.

Comment: The syntax I'm using on db2 is 
SELECT t1.id
FROM
  (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS t1(id)
left join mydb.ACCOUNT a
  on a.id = t1.id
and a.id is null;

Comment: So your Db2-server runs on Z/OS and is it V11 New Function Mode.

Comment: Db2 v11 for Z/OS supports EXCEPT in fullselect.  Try `select * from
(SELECT * FROM
  (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(7), (7000000)) as T(ID) )
EXCEPT
  (SELECT ID
  FROM ACCOUNT );`

Comment: Thanks.  Stll complains "illegal symbol "(".  Through experimentation I can see it is complaning about the ( that comes AFTER the values and before the 1.

Comment: Seems Fb2 v11 for Z/OS rejects the values clause in this context. Maybe a CTE is needed.

Comment: You can select one row at a time from sysibm.sysdummy1 and union them (instead of using the values clause). Ugly, so there's probably a better way.

Comment: You're right.  Post that suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it accepted.  I got the below to work:

select 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 3 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 4 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 5 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 6 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 7 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 8 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 9 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
  EXCEPT
    select id from ACCOUNT a;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Db2 v11 for Z/OS does not support the values clause in this context, although Db2 v11 on Linux/Unix/Windows does support it.

Although it's  ugly, and there may be a better way, you might try:

`SELECT * FROM
  (select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union
  select 2 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union
  select 3 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union
  select 4 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union
  select 7 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union
  select 7000000 from sysibm.sysdummy1 )
EXCEPT
  SELECT ID
  FROM ACCOUNT;`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can try with a CTA :

```
WITH
T(ID) AS (VALUES 1,2,3,4,7,7000000)
SELECT ID FROM T
EXCEPT
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `sysibm.sysdummy1`:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM (SELECT 1 as ID FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
     ) as t
EXCEPT
  SELECT ID
  FROM ACCOUNT;
```